# Is it possible to modify methods of an object instance using reflection

Tags: php, reflection, orm, domain-model

What I'm trying to do is create a domain model with a Plain Old PHP Object.
The I'm creating a library which will do all the infrastructure stuff.
So one of my models looks like this

```
class Project {
  public $id;
  public $name;
  public $typeId;

  private $type;

  public function getType() {
    return $this->type;
  }

  public function setType(Type $type) {
    $this->typeId = $type->id;
    $this->type = $type;
  }
}
```

Now if create a new Project and call `setType` with a valid Type object and save the project instance using the ORM both the project and type is saved. But then I load the Project and use `getType` method I want the ORM to have modified this method transparently to load the object from persitence. So this method here:

```
public function getType() {
  return $this->type;
}
```

to be transparently changed into:

```
public function getType() {
  if (is_null($this->type) {
    $this->type = $this->adapter->findById('table', $this->typeId);
  }

  return $this->type; // or return parent::getType();
}
```

Outlet PHP uses eval to create a Proxy class for Project called Project_Proxy but sometimes there will be subclasses of Project so I am searching for a solution by using Reflection API if there is a way.

I have search google but haven't found anyway to change a method behaviour

**Edit:** or would it be a good idea to use Outlet PHP's eval method to create Proxy Classes for my models and all subclasses of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no builtin way of doing this. And although you can do that using the [PECL extension called runkit](http://pecl.php.net/package/runkit), I would strongly recommend finding another solution. Changing the implementation of functions you can't know *anything* about is very dangerous and might lead to bugs where debugging a single such bug can take longer than writing the `if (is_null(...` statements for *all* your functions.

BTW: don't use `is_null()`, since you might fetch null values from the database over and over again. You should store the fetched values in a separate variable.

Comment: But if i write if (is_null(... inside the model I am coupling the model with the DataAbstractionLayer by calling `$this->adapter`. Also `is_null` is not actually checking a database field but checking the property which holds the Related entity

Comment: Quite on the contrary: If you would be implementing logic *for* the class *outside* the class, you would defy OO programming rules. You have a database connection object (I'm assuming that `$this->adapter` is one) and this is called dependency injection, and is currently considered good practice.

Comment: The issue about `is_null()` is that calling `$user->getFirstName()` twice will query the database twice if the column `firstname` of the `users` table has a `NULL` value.

Comment: Thanks, then I will go with the Dependency Injection.

Comment: I am actually not using getters and setters for properties but only to get related entities. So to get firstname I would use `$customer->firstName` but to get the street address object for the user I would user `$customer->getAddress()->street`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the reflection [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) on php.net, it appears to me it is impossible to modify on the flight a method.

You should try to do it in a different way.