# PHP overriding method of an object

Tags: php, oop, overriding

Let's say I have an object of type A, looking like this:

```
class A{

    private $item;
...
...
...
...
    public function getItem(){
        return $this->item;
    }
}


$obj = new A();
```

is there any way, that without modifying source code of class A I can **override method `getItem` only for object `$obj`?**

if yes, then how?

I tried to do it like in code below:

```
class A{

    private $item = 5;
    public function getItem(){
        return $this->item;
    }
}


$obj = new A();

echo $obj->getItem();

$obj->getItem = function(){return 10;};

echo $obj->getItem();
```

but [it returns](https://3v4l.org/7YKZH) result of original `getItem` method twice

The thing I want to achieve is *replace* method I want only in some objects, don't want to modify base class

@EDIT

I played with code a little bit and found something interesting:

```
<?php

class A{

    private $item = 5;
    public function getItem(){
        return $this->item;
    }
}


$obj = new A();

echo $obj->getItem()."\n";

$obj->getItem = function(){return 10;};

echo $obj->getItem()."\n";

$fun = $obj->getItem;

echo $fun()."\n";
```

[this code prints](https://3v4l.org/HRe8Q) `5 5 10`, so something in object has changed, but why it isn't a method? Is it impossible to `replace` method like that?

Comment: What about a child class?

Comment: This is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). If you want objects to behave differently, then you should have different objects.

Comment: @AlexHowansky the thing is I need to do this only in one place of code, and I thought this would be easiest way to achieve it

Comment: @alanfcm yeah I thought of it, but I have to do it only once in project, so I thought of it just because I was curious if it could  work like that, is it possible to override methods like that

Comment: `class B extends A { private $item = 'something else';
    public function getItem(){
        return $this->item;
    }}` then `$object = new B;`

Comment: @AbraCadaver yeah, I know about this, but I asked just out of curiosity if it's possible to 'replace' method in some object using method like that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible, and luckily so, as it would pose a huge security risk.

[Reflection API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) does allow accessing of methods, but not changing its implemention.

See also
* [Is it possible to modify methods of an object instance using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754084/is-it-possible-to-modify-methods-of-an-object-instance-using-reflection)
* http://www.stubbles.org/archives/65-Extending-objects-with-new-methods-at-runtime.html

---

**Update**

While you cannot replace the implementiation of a function, you can change the value of a otherwise hidden field using reflection:

```
<?php

class A {

  private $item = 5;

  public function getItem() {
    return $this->item;
  }

}

$obj = new A();

$reflect = new ReflectionClass($obj);
$property = $reflect->getProperty('item');
$property->setAccessible(TRUE);
$property->setValue($obj, 10);

echo $obj->getItem(); // 10
```