# Call function when another function (from my vendor folder) is called

Tags: php

Currently I am stuck with the following problem: I wan't to call a function when another function from a dependency in my vendor folder is called.

I have taken a look at some of the questions about this problem, but all answers require you to edit the code of function you want to listen to.

My function in the vendor folder looks like this:

```php
public function setText(string $text) {
   $this->text = $text;
}
```

Whenever the `setText` function gets called, I want to execute this function:

```php
public function doSomething() {
   (stuff)
}
```

How would I go about this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to modify methods of an object instance using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754084/is-it-possible-to-modify-methods-of-an-object-instance-using-reflection)

Comment: @MarkusZeller nope, thanks for your time though :)

Comment: Simply, you can't. That is what the answer told. `Does this answer your question?` is inserted by SO. Elegant version is to extend the vendor class and use that instance.

Comment: Okay, I will try that then. Thanks